# In Unity, how to apply Priority change of MenuItem immediately?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

If I change the priority of a menuitem, it won’t take effect immediately.(The menuitem will be in the same order, ignore the change.)
I have to restart the editor to apply the priority change.

What can I do to make this change applied immediately?
Is there any script that can pretend an editor restart?

Comment: Did your scripts recompile after you changed the priority?

Comment: yes, it is recompiled

Comment: But my menu item moved. I tried the priority 0 and 9999.

Comment: I'm using Unity2021. Which version are you using?

Comment: https://blog.redbluegames.com/guide-to-extending-unity-editors-menus-b2de47a746db
In this article, it also says the priority of a menuitem won’t take effect immediately